# Help clarifying this property of $\omega$ limit sets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and $f:X \to X$ be continuous. For $x \in X$, the $\omega$-limit set $\omega(x)$ is defined as all cluster points of $(x(n))$, defined as $x(n+1)=f(x(n))$ with $x(0)=x$.

Wikipedia claims that the limit set is always $f$-invariant, provided $f$ is continuous. However, no constraint was placed on $X$. $X$ could be non-complete then. I want to make sure this is true because a set might not contain it's limit points. I could have a sequence of rationals converge to an irrational. I tried finding a proof of this online yet only found ones for the continuous case (not the discrete case as I described).

Could someone confirm whether this really is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an "if--then" statement: **if** $p \in \omega(x)$ **then** $f(p) \in \omega(x)$.

And that's pretty easy to prove: assuming $p \in \omega(x)$ it follows that $p = \lim_{i \to \infty} x(n_i)$ for some subsequence $n_i$. It follows that $f(p) = \lim_{i \to \infty} f(x(n_i)) = x(n_{i+1})$ (this is where continuity of $f$ is used), and therefore $f(p) \in \omega(x)$.

**Added:** Regarding your comment below, let's consider the case of a metric space $Y$ and a subspace $X \subset Y$ such that $X$ is complete with respect to the metric that is obtained by restriction of the metric on $Y$. I'll leave it as an exercise in topology to verify an important conclusion in this case: $X$ is a closed subset of $Y$, and therefore if a sequence in $X$ converges to a limit in $Y$ that limit is actually contained in $X$.

So suppose now that $f : Y \to Y$ is continuous, and that $f(X)=X$, so we can restrict to $f : X \to X$. In this situation, if $x \in X$, if $p \in Y$, and if $p \in \omega(x)$ then we can conclude that $p$ is a limit of a sequence in $X$, namely some sequence of the form $(x(n_i))$ with $1 \le n_1 < n_2 < \cdots$. But as said above $X$ is closed in $Y$, and therefore $p \in X$.

Comment: I see. Are we not assuming that the limit set is a subset of $X$? Or is this implied from the continuity of $f$?

Comment: Well, yes, $(x(n))$ is a set of points of $X$, and its limit points are all points in $X$.

Comment: How do we know its limit points are in X? What if X is the rationals, and we have a sequence of rationals converging to an irrational (hence not in X)?

Comment: Wikipedia definitions, written by multiple non-coordinated authors and spanning several interlinked pages, are not the place to find precise definitions. If your desire is to find a self-contained treatment of topological dynamics, you would do better to consult a good textbook.

Comment: Meanwhile, here is a short, rigorous definition of $\omega$ limit sets. I have written this definition to consistent with your post, and to be self-contained **assuming** that you are familiar with basic topology such as the first few chapters of Munkres book. Given a metric space $X$, a continuous function $f : X \to X$, and a point $x \in X$, the *$\omega$-limit set of $x$* is defined to be the subset $\omega(x) \subset X$ consisting of all points $p \in X$ for which there exists a sequence of integers $1 \le n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < ...$ such that $\lim_{i \to \infty} f(x_i) = p$.

Comment: Notice: the definition *requires* $p$ to be an element of $X$. With that requirement, it does not matter whether the metric space $X$ is embedded as a subset of some larger metric space. If you liked you *could* consider $f : X \to X$ to be the restriction of some continuous function $g : Y \to Y$ such that $X$ is a subspace of a larger metric space $Y$ and such that $g(X)=X$, but the $\omega$-limit set of $x \in X$ *with respect to the given function $g$* will most likely be different from the $\omega$-limit set of $x$ *with respect to the given function $f$*.

Comment: Thank you for this and the clarification on wikipedia's writing style, this helps a lot. On a side note, in your setup, if $X$ is a complete metric space and a subset of metric space $Y$, and I know $f$ is continuous on $X$, can I know for certain that the limit set $\omega(x,f)$ will be a subset of $X$?

By the way, if you add these extra comments in your answer, I will accept it!

Comment: I added some details, although the hypotheses of your comment are not strong enough, and I replaced them with some sufficiently strong hypotheses.